# Can linear model give more prediction accuracy than random forest,decision tree,neural network?

Tags: neural-network, linear-regression, random-forest, decision-tree

I have calculated the following parameters after applying the following algorithms on a dataset from kaggle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLuTK.png)

In the above case,linear model is giving the best results.
Are the above results correct and can linear model actually give better results than other 3 in any case?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

According to AUC criterion this classification is perfect (1 is theoretical maximum). This means a clear difference in the data. In this case, it makes no sense to talk about differences in the results of methods. Another point is that you can play with methods parameters (you likely will get slightly different results) and other methods can become better. But real result will be indistinguishable. Sophisticated methods are invented for sophisticated data. This is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

> All models are wrong, some are useful. - George Box

In terms of classification, a model would be effective as long as it could nicely fit the classification boundaries.

For binary classification case, supposing your data is perfectly linearly separable, then linear model will do the job - actually the "best" job since any more complicated models won't perform better.

If your +'s and -'s are somehow a bit scattered when they cannot be separated by a line (actually hyperplane), then linear model could be beaten by decision tree simply because decision trees can provide classification boundary of more complex shape (cubes).

Then random forest may beat decision tree as classification boundary of random forest is more flexible.

However, as we mentioned early, linear model still has its time.